# JavaScript conditional ignoring IF

Tags: javascript, php

I have a conditional statement set on the url,I tested both the IF and ELSE and it does work with a simple document.write. However, I am trying to output Php i the conditional but it just always outputs the else statement, Php is not my strongest language:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(
window.location.href=="mywebsite.com"
)
{

    document.write('<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__("Qty:") ?></label><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("Qty") ?>" class="input-text qty" />')

}else{

    document.write('<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__(' ') ?></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("Qty") ?>" class="input-text qty" />')

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` contains the full URL. If you just want to check the hostname part of the URL, use `window.location.host`.

```
if (window.location.host == "mywebsite.com") {
    ...
}
```

Another option would be to do all the work on the server.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'mywebsite.com') {
?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__("Qty:") ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("Qty") ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<?php } else {
?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__(' ') ?></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__("Qty") ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<?php }
```

Comment: The thing is, I put an alert im the IF statement and it worked but since I included the `doucment.write` in the If and Else it only shows the Else regarding which page I am on as I want to change the content depending on a specific URL

Comment: Why are you doing this in JS anyway? Do it in PHP: `if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'mywebsite.com') { echo ... } else { echo ... }`

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` returns the full URL including protocol (so `http://www.mywebsite.com`).

You could alert the value of `window.location.href` to see exactly what it's returning, and update your if statement to match it.

Comment: The thing is, I put an alert im the IF statement and it worked but since I included the `doucment.write` in the If and Else it only shows the Else regarding which page I am on as I want to change the content depending on a specific URL